# Why are files created in git bash not visible in Windows explorer?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

So I just moved from Ubuntu to Windows (read forced to move, thanks to compatibility issues) and am using Git Bash to pull in my files. I've noticed something extremely strange.

Git Bash is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\`, and when I first run the Git Bash program, the default location is this. Normal right? Right.

But here's the weird part..

When I run the command `mkdir srv` in the Git Bash command line, I can see it in the Bash window - but I **can't** see it in Windows Explorer?! What the heck. Same thing happens with files created using `vi` in the CLI. Invisible in Windows Explorer. (Yes, I have enabled the `Show hidden files` option in Explorer, so it's not that).

Here are some snapshots (no, I'm not blind - nor am I insane). Help?
[image: Now you see it]
[image: Now you don't]

Comment: Step 1: run `pwd` to find out in which directory you actually are. Step 2: Run the explorer as Admin to make sure there are no permission issues

Comment: @Chronial bulls eye. It was the `Run as administrator` deal that sealed it. Post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Why on Earth are you running `git bash` as Administrator?

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm just glad it works lol. I guess explorer just has to be running with the same credentials as `git bash` in order for this to work.

Comment: @FloatingRock: Sure, it works, but if you had run git bash from an ordinary user account in the first place you wouldn't have had this problem. Only use an administrative account when you actually *need* to. You *will* make mistakes, and you *will* shoot yourself in the foot; good habits let you limit the damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might not be able to see the folder because of missing privileges. Try running your explorer as Administrator and look again.

Comment: Note [under Windows 8 you *can't* run explorer as Administrator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a6e4cff3-0581-4029-b32c-594ff2f511e9/how-can-you-do-a-run-as-administrator-with-file-explorer?forum=w8itprogeneral). From that forum, you either have to disable UAC or "either modify the NTFS permissions and add yourself, or open an admin command prompt and do what you intended to do."

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solutions above didn't help me. However, I copied the hidden directories to another place via `git bash`. Then I copied them once again via windows explorer to the original place. Now they've become visible. I created those **invisible** folders via `git bash` with `git clone` command before.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, but with file attributes, not with missing privileges.
In cmd under  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\` run command  [attrib](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib)

> attrib *

You will know if `srv` folder has System or Hidden file attribute.

If you would like to view it in cmd then use `dir /a:s`